# Type "address[]" not supported for state variable

Tags: solidity, nethereum

I have a very strange problem. Many solidity contract examples use `address` struct types as state variables. But my smart contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract ProductItem {
address[] _owners;
address _currentOwner;
address _nextOwner;
string _productDigest;

function ProductItem(string productDigest) {
    _currentOwner = msg.sender;
    _productDigest = productDigest;
}

function setNextOwner(address nextOwner) returns(bool set) {
    if (_currentOwner != msg.sender) {
        return false;
    }
    _nextOwner = nextOwner;
    return true;
}

function confirmOwnership() returns(bool confirmed) {
    if (_nextOwner != msg.sender) {
        return false;
    }
    _owners.push(_nextOwner);
    _currentOwner = _nextOwner;
    _nextOwner = address(0);
    return true;
}

function getOwner() constant returns(address owner) {
    return _currentOwner;
}

function getOwners() constant returns(address[] owners) {
    return _owners;
}

function getProduct() returns (string product) {
    return _productDigest;
}
}
```

gives me error in web ide:

> Untitled:4:5: Error: Type "address[]" not supported for state variable.
>     
>   address[] _owners;
>     
>   ^---------------^"

If i ignore this error and try to deploy and call function, e.g. `getProduct()` it results with null.

Comment: This appears to be a package problem. Having the same issue with the `solc`  npm package, just for one address, not even an array. Compiles fine in browser-solidity.

Comment: i have a same issue, transactions are happening but i am not able to see the count and item details
can anyone resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I've used the Solidity realtime compiler and runtime connected to a local `geth` node with version `Geth/v1.4.13-stable/linux/go1.5.1` and your code compiles and deploys perfectly.

I have made one change and that is to add `constant` keyword to the `getProduct(...)` method as you are not changing any state in this method.

Here is the modified code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract ProductItem {
    address[] _owners;
    address _currentOwner;
    address _nextOwner;
    string _productDigest;

    function ProductItem(string productDigest) {
        _currentOwner = msg.sender;
        _productDigest = productDigest;
    }

    function setNextOwner(address nextOwner) returns(bool set) {
        if (_currentOwner != msg.sender) {
           return false;
        }
        _nextOwner = nextOwner;
        return true;
    }

    function confirmOwnership() returns(bool confirmed) {
        if (_nextOwner != msg.sender) {
            return false;
        }
        _owners.push(_nextOwner);
        _currentOwner = _nextOwner;
        _nextOwner = address(0);
        return true;
    }

    function getOwner() constant returns(address owner) {
        return _currentOwner;
    }

    function getOwners() constant returns(address[] owners) {
        return _owners;
    }

    function getProduct() constant returns (string product) {
       return _productDigest;
    }
}
```

Here is the screen showing the deployment of the modified code, and that the constant method `getProduct()` returns "ProductOne".

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer! Actually, for now non-constant version of getProduct() also works in web ide. Maybe it is an issue with a library (Nethereum .net).